# How to make Google custom search results load first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-custom-search

So I want to run some javascript/jQuery code after all google custom search results have loaded. This is my code so far:

```
var myCallback = function(){
    $('body').prepend('<script>var url1 = $("a.gs-title").attr("href");$("a").css("color", "#000");console.log("First URL: "+url1);\<\/\s\cript>');
}
window.__gcse = {
    callback: myCallback
};
(function() {
    var cx = '014695096701266588579:phi8azyxlp4';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
    '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

If I run the code from inside myCallback() in the console after the page loads, it does exactly what I want. Please help, I have literally searched for three days and I can't find anything that works!

Comment: Your description isn't clear.  What do you want to happen exactly, and what is happening now?

Comment: @raduation What I want is to be able to manipulate/execute jquery or js code on the custom search results. Right now I can see in the console that the js is running before the results load, so nothing happens.

Comment: You need to post more of your code.  Also, the callback may not be doing what you think it is doing.  According to the documentation, the callback runs at this time: "Specifies the callback function to call when the initialization process is completed."  So, you likely need to trigger your callback in a different place in your code.

Comment: Perhaps you can trigger your callback after your 'search' button is clicked.

Comment: You may not be executing the callback at the right time, as @Clayton suggested.  Google may add the results dynamically after the DOM is ready and your callback gets called.  In this case, I would set up a timer that periodically checks for the presence of certain selectors in the response, i.e. the search results.  Then, run your function.